# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли выражение "состояние коммуникаций в любом поселке требует определенных профессиональных навыков"

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил:"состояние коммуникаций в любом поселке требует определенных профессиональных навыков обслуживающего их персонала"

Answer (score 1):

Добавления в фразе явно не хватает. Иначе получается, что речь идет о навыках коммуникаций)Только не требует, а лучше сказать, зависит от ...

Answer (score 0):

Меня тоже смущает сочетание "состояние требует". Здесь бы нужно, мне кажется, обозначить задачу, для решения которой требуются навыки. Состояние, как верно указано, может зависеть от наличия этих навыков, а если сохранять "требует",  то поставить "бесперебойное функционирование" или "контроль состояния".

Итого: бесперебойное функционирование коммуникаций в любом посёлке требует от обслуживающего их персонала определенных профессиональных навыков, или: состояние коммуникаций в любом посёлке зависит от наличия определённых профессиональных навыков у обслуживающего их персонала.